# Image not displayed in jsp in Maven Project

Tags: spring, image, maven, jsp

I know this question is answered a million times but I have tried every possible suggestion and nothing works. Here is the structure of my project:
[image]

I have tried 3 different directories to put my img.jpg, but non of them displays the image

Here is my jsp:
main.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  
 <img value="<%=getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>" src="/webapp/WEB-INF/imags/img.jpg"/>

<br>

<h1>The FoRoom</h1>
<h2>Millions of users communicate everyday</h2>

<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logIn">Log In</a>
<br>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addUser">Sign Up (Add
    User)</a>
<br>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logInAsAdmin">Log In as
    an Administrator</a>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the 1st comment section:

```
 <!-- 1st comment section -->
<!-- no error with GET!!!
  <input type="image" src="C:\Users\MyUser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC\images\img.jpg">
  <input type="image" src="C:/Users/MyUser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SpringMVC/images/img.jpg" >
  <input type="image" src="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>">
  <input type="image" src="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>">
  <input type="image" src="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <input type="image" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/imags/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <input type="image" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <input type="hidden" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/imags/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <input type="hidden" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <img value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>" src="/webapp/images/img.jpg"/>
  <img value="<%=getServletContext().getRealPath("/imags/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <img alt="/src/main/webapp/images/img.jpg" src="/src/main/webapp/images/img.jpg">
<br>
  <img alt="/main/webapp/images/img.jpg" src="/main/webapp/images/img.jpg">
  <br>
  <img alt="/webapp/images/img.jpg" src="/webapp/images/img.jpg">
  <br>
  <img alt="/webapp/images/img.gif" src="/webapp/images/img.gif">
  <img value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>" src="/webapp/images/img.jpg"/>
  <tools:img path="/images/img.jpg"/>
  <img alt="d" src="< %=request.getContextPath() %>/webapp/images/img.jpg">

 <img src="C:/Users/MyUser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SpringMVC/images/img.jpg" >
 <img src="C:\Users\MyUser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC\images\img.jpg">
  <img src="C:\Users\MyUser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC\images\img.jpg" width="48" height="48">

  <c:url value="/imags/img.jpg" var="img" /> (head) , <img src = "/imags/img.jpg" > (body)
  <br>
-->
```

Here is the second comment section:

```
<!-- 2nd comment section -->
<!-- PROBLEM WITH GET
  <img src="<c:url value='./webapp/images/img.jpg' />">
  <img alt="<c:url value='/webapp/images/img.jpg' />" src="<c:url value='/webapp/images/img.jpg' />">
  <br>
  <img src="<c:url value='./images/img.jpg' />">
  <img alt="<c:url value='/images/img.jpg' />" src="<c:url value='/images/img.jpg' />">
  <img src="<c:url value='images/img.jpg' />">
  <img src="<c:url value='/images/img.jpg' />" alt="p">
  <br>
  <img alt="webapp/images/img.jpg" src="webapp/images/img.jpg"></img> 
  <img alt="<c:url value='/webapp/images/img.jpg' />" src="<c:url value='webapp/images/img.jpg' />">

  <img alt="a" src="< %=request.getContextPath() %>/images/img.jpg">
  <img alt="b" src='< %=request.getContextPath() + "/images/img.jpg" %> '>
  <img alt="c" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/img.jpg" />
  <img src="${pageContext.servletContext}/images/img.jpg"/>
  <img src="${pageContext.servletContext}/webapp/images/img.jpg"/>
  <input type="image" src="images/img.jpg" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/img.jpg") %>" name="img.jpg">
  <input type="image" src="images/img.jpg" value="< %=getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>">
-->
```

In the comments sections is everything I have tried but failed. In the 1st comment section the image is not displayed but no error is shown. When I run my project with a command of the 2nd comment section I get a warning message. For example if I try this:

```
<img src="<c:url value='./webapp/images/img.jpg' />">
```

I get this:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /SpringMVC_Hibernate_Setup/%3Cc:url%20value='./webapp/images/img.jpg'%20/%3E
```

I have mostly tried to display the img.jpg from the webapp/images. I know that image folder in the WEB-INF is a big NO NO, but at this point I don't know what else to do.

Any help would be very appreciated!!!

EDIT!!!
this is the tutorial I followed: https://www.javaspringclub.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-example/
I made some changes, but the core is the same.

Comment: if the image is under `src/main/resources/`, then it cannot be rendered unless you tell the webapp that it should look into the resources. A webapp delivers static files from under `src/main/webapp/`. If you're using spring-web-mvc, you should have a look into `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)` with this you could e.g. render resources from a JAR file under a specific path

Comment: besides that, `No mapping for GET /SpringMVC_Hibernate_Setup/%3Cc:url%20value='./webapp/images/img.jpg'%20/%3E`  should show you that `<c:url />` is **not evaluated as the JSTL tag**, but passed as a String. Hence I believe that you forgot the *taglib declaration* line for the JSTL-core-tags. add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` to your JSP file and see what happens next.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you so much! I spent days trying to figure out my problem. I suspected it had something to do with my WebMvcConfigurer but I didn't know what to do. After a few tries and changes in my code I finally loaded the picture!